# Javascript Array(With objects inside) to PHP to insert into a database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

Right, I have an array which has objects inside and it looks like this:

[image: Array with objects]

I would like that to be inserted into my database through an AJAX call to my php file.

I have tried JSON.stringfy on the array and the result i get back in the database is

[{"task":"Tyres","notes":"Hello","completed":"True"},{"task":"Tyres","notes":"All Four Tyres need doing","completed":"True"},{"task":"Tyres","notes":"All Four Tyres need doing","completed":"True"},{"task":"Tyres","notes":"All Four Tyres need doing","completed":"True"}]

The double quotes have been replaced with " I realise this is the symbol of the quotes however I would like the quotes.

I  also tried sending the array and the database returns blank.

[image: Javascript code]

[image: PHP code]

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking for. Do you simply want to store the string in the database?

Comment: I dont get the problem, you store json as a string in the database then you can give it to the client when needed. What do you want to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP Data Objects (PDO) for your database inserts.  It allows you to make prepared statements to prevent injection attacks. You won't need functions like "safeString" and can guarantee that what you put in is what you get out.

Here's an example of what it looks like.  You can see that parameters are named and we pass values in an array with the names as keys.

```
$sql = "UPDATE mutable SET json=:json WHERE id=:id";
$statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([":json" => $json, ":id" => $id]);
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [PHP json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) to translate back to object. But beware that it will convert back to StdClass only. You need to read it and handle proper transformations. e.g.:

```
$carChecklist = json_decode($_POST['checklist']);
echo $carChecklist[0]->tyres;
```

Should return 'Tyres';